# Running "sass:dist" (sass) task Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - undefined

Tags: sass, gruntjs, npm

I'm trying to create a gruntfile which will compile all my scripts, css, and html files (as most grunt files do), and I put in a few commands for sass to compile and put into a separate folder.  I hit 'Grunt' and it outputs the error:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - undefined
```

the parts that call on my sass in the gruntfile.js are as follows:

Configure Task

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: false,
      cwd: 'styles',
      src: [ '**/*.scss' ],
      dest: 'build',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  }
},
```

Register Tasks

```
});
grunt.registerTask(
  'scripts',
  'compiles the Javascript files.',
  [ 'coffee', 'uglify', 'clean:scripts' ]
);
grunt.registerTask(
  'stylesheets',
  'compiles the stylesheets.',
  [ 'autoprefixer', 'cssmin', 'sass', 'clean:stylesheets' ]
);
grunt.registerTask(
  'build',
  'Compiles all of the assets and copies the files to the build directory.',
  [ 'clean:build', 'copy', 'stylesheets', 'sass', 'scripts', 'jade' ]
);
grunt.registerTask(
  'default',
  'Watches the project for changes, automatically builds them and runs a server.',
  [ 'build', 'connect', 'watch' ]
);
```

Load the Tasks

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
```

Comment: It seems a ruby error. Which Ruby version are you using? and sass gem?

Take a look in this Github issue: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/issues/63

Comment: I'm currently using Ruby 2.2.3 (x64) and Sass 3.4.19 (Selective Steve).  In my package.json file I reference grunt-contrib-sass": "0.9.x

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. The root cause was that the *sass > dist > files* configuration was incorrect.

Downgrading to 0.4.x showed the real error. Once I fix the configuration, I have upgraded back to the latest grunt-contrib-sass version and it worked ok.

Answer (score 2):

I downgraded grunt-contrib-sass to 0.4.x and it worked out.  Thank you for the help.